# CSS/SCSS background color like Microsoft Sign In page

Tags: html, css, sass

I really like the style background color of the Microsoft Sign In page and I kinda want to learn about that also apply to my project for school. But when I inspect it, I can't see any style codes. Does CSS or SCSS can do that? I'm not really sure. Thanks
Here is the page that I'm talking about: [Microsoft Sign In](https://login.live.com/login.srf)

Comment: Can you please attach an image of the Microsoft Sign In page instead, because I'm currently logged in my microsoft accout. So to be able to understand what you want I've to logged out of my account.

Comment: If you haven't discovered developer tools in your browser,  now is the time.   Chrome has great dev tools,  firefox did too last i checked.   This will allow you to inspect the DOM and view things like background colors and css rules.   Don't be afraid to use multiple browsers if your browser of choice isn't ad useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can see my fiddle to get Idea how to do this.
https://jsfiddle.net/rkm1994/0ewnsu7h/
`- For Login`

source:- https://speckyboy.com/login-pages-html5-css/

Comment: Can you edit the relevant piece(s) of code into your answer? If anything happens to that JSFiddle, your answer will become useless.

Answer (score 0):

```css
div{
            height: 500px;
            width: 500px;
            background-image: linear-gradient(120deg,#f0c9f8,#f7eff6);
        }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

here is the thing i tried to make it for you hope it will help for the background...